# Como seleciono todos os registros da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como faço para selecionar todos os registros no select abaixo:

```
$select = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS id_mark, SUM(a.rate) AS rate, b.name_mark, b.id 
           FROM tb_comment a, tb_mark b 
           WHERE a.id_mark=b.id AND b.id_category=:id_c 
           GROUP BY a.id_mark, b.name_mark 
           ORDER BY rate DESC 
           LIMIT $start_pg, $amount_pg";
```

Por que nesse **SELECT** está apenas selecionando os 'itens' que tem algum valor em **'rate'**, não teria como fazer para selecionar tudo e aqueles que não tiver valor mostrar '0' como valor?

Na tabela **tb_mark** tem todos os cadastros*[tópicos]* e na tabela **tb_comment** tem todos os registros dos comentários dos *tópicos*, e o select só está exibindo os cadastro que tem algum registro na tabela **tb_comment**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim pega todas as linhas da tabela

`SELECT id_mark, COALESCE(a.rate, 0) AS rate, b.name_mark, b.id 
 FROM tb_comment a, tb_mark b 
 WHERE a.id_mark=b.id AND b.id_category=:id_c ORDER BY rate DESC`